# Having issues subracting two arrays with 2400 rows and 1 colum each

Tags: arrays, matlab

Program: MATLAB 2013

Dimension of `RANKPosY` and `RANKPosZ`: 2402 rows by 1 column

Variable class: 2402 x 1 (cell)

My goal is to subtract `RANKPosY` - `RANKPosZ`, but when I compile and run I get the following error

```
RANKPosY - RANKPosZ

ERROR MESSAGE: **Undefined function 'minus' for input arguments of type
'cell'.**
```

I read other stackoverflow solutions and those have not worked still get the same error as before.

[image: MATLAB Workspace]

Comment: What is in an individual cell of `RANKposY` or `RANKposY`? Please look over [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a guide to posting your example data/code.

Comment: You had two issues here - you're using a cell instead of a numeric array, and you were doing that because you had characters not numbers! When asking questions, ensure you provide all the information necessary to reproduce and solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `cellfun` to apply `minus` on the cell arrays:

```
a = {1, 3, 5, 7};
b = {1, 2, 3, 4};
cellfun(@minus, a, b);

ans =

     0     1     2     3
```

Comment: I complied and ran that code for my data set and got this error when both datasets are the same length.                                                                                                                            EDU>> Ankle = cellfun(@minus, RANKPosY, RANKPosZ);
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of those cell arrays?

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot of my workspace. My main goal is plot timestamp (x-axis) vs angle (y-axis)

Comment: i figured it out. i just used str2double and was able to subtract

Comment: Great! Please consider [upvoting and/or accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: You can also get the same result with `[a{:}]-[b{:}]` which will basically produce the same result, maybe a bit faster.